# Renaming the 100GB Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have more than 100GB size of table in my database I want to rename the table name. Is it a good idea?

Comment: I've retagged this question with oracle,sql,mysql for more good answers.

Comment: Upvoting for the epic randomness of the question.  What does the size of the table have to do with renaming it, lol?

Answer (score 1):

Is not a problem at all! Problem if you would change a column. Make sure nobody refers to the old name.

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon your version of mysql. Version 5.1 and 5.5 can do a rename by altering the .frm file and renaming the file. I'm not sure about earlier versions. Be careful of other alter table commands  because it may need to create a copy of the table data.

Edit: This is also dependent upon the MySQL storage engine as well. MyISAM and InnoDB tables can be renamed by changing the metadata (i.e renaming the file). But there are some storage engines which will perform the copy operation to do something as simple as a table rename.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is no dependency between the size and the name. If you don't have to change the queries in your code or stored procedures, you are good to go.

Comment: If there are foreign keys referencing the one being renamed, you will most probably not be allowed 'to go'.

Answer (score 0):

After changing several table names to follow the ***current*** naming standards we found a legacy program which had the table name hard coded and had to change everything back.  To comply with the naming standard for the new app being build we created a view for each offending table with the current naming standard.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it should never ever create a problem.  The name of the table should not have any dependencies on what the contents of the same table are.  Unless you are trying to mess with system tables, in which case the results are not going to be pretty.

Comment: *'The name of the table should not have any dependencies'* – What about foreign keys?